# Child routes not working whenever 'children' property is applied in Angular2

Tags: angular

Whenever I apply 'children' property, it gives the error that 'Cannot find routes' although they have been written properly.

Following is the screenshot of error :

[image: Error Screenshot]

Following is the code :

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule}                   from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule }             from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Http, HttpModule}           from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule }              from '@angular/forms';
import { Router,RouterModule }      from '@angular/router';


import {AppComponent}               from "./app.component";

import {ComponentsComponent}          from "./app/components/components.component";
import {TrainingComponent}            from "./app/training/training.component";

import {ComponentsModule}             from "./app/components/components.module";
import {TrainingModule}               from "./app/training/training.module";

import {DemoHelloWorldComponent}    from './app/training/helloWorld/demoHelloWorld.component';

import {HelloWorldComponent}        from "./app/training/helloWorld/helloWorld.component"
import {CompositeComponentComponent} from './app/training/compositeComponent/compositeComponent.component';
import {TrainingComponentComponent} from './app/training/trainingComponent/trainingComponent.component';
import {TrainingModuleComponent} from './app/training/trainingModule/trainingModule.component';
import {RestServiceProviderComponent} from './app/training/restServiceProvider/restServiceProvider.component';



@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        TrainingModule,

        RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
        path: 'training',
        component:TrainingComponent,
        children:[
                {
                    path: 'hello-world',
                    component:HelloWorldComponent

                },

                {
                  path: 'training-component',
                  component:TrainingComponentComponent

                },
                {
                  path: 'training-module',
                  component:TrainingModuleComponent


                },
                {
                  path: 'composite-components',
                  component:CompositeComponentComponent

                },
                {
                  path: 'rest-service-provider',
                  component:RestServiceProviderComponent

                }
        ]
        },
        {
          path: 'demo-components',
          component:ComponentsComponent,
        }
      ]),
      ],

    declarations:
    [  
        AppComponent,
        ComponentsComponent,
        TrainingComponent,
        HelloWorldComponent,
        CompositeComponentComponent,
        TrainingComponentComponent,
        TrainingModuleComponent,
        RestServiceProviderComponent,
           DemoHelloWorldComponent

    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
     // Diagnostic only: inspect router configuration
  constructor(router: Router) {  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you just move the child route up to a regular route? I have not seen a situation like yours where child routes are defined on an AppModule. It seems to me you want these child routes defined in your Training feature Module.

Comment: when I move them in training feature module they work fine but replace the main router-outlet to give the view and that is not what I want.

Comment: Do you have a router-outlet in your TrainingComponent template? Child routes should be loaded into router-outlets of the component loaded. In addition, if you want to load two components side-by-side, you would need to use auxiliary routes.

Comment: @birwin I do have a router-outlet in TrainingComponent template but it ignores that and replaces the main router-outlet. How to use auxiliary routes?

Comment: http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add default route for training because I think this is necessary.

```
path: 'training',
children:[
  {
    path: '',
    component: TrainingComponent
  }
  (...)
```

Comment: and add to it ```pathMatch: 'full'```